# Как по нажатию на кнопку убрать элемент с окна программы?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Button Click="HidePanel"  

<TextBox  x:Name="textBlockHead"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Миллионом различных способов.

Например:

```
void HidePanel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlockHead.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```